# Downloading an XML file on Android, storing it and then using it locally

Tags: android, xml

I am a beginner in Android programming, and am working on an app that shows a list of products, and onclick, a new activity shows the details about that particular product.

This list of products is stored online as an xml file, with the obvious problem that the device needs to be connected to the internet every time it is used. I want the device to work offline as well.

One way to do it will be to store the latest xml locally. But my products will get updated very often. How do I keep my local copy of the xml file updated? And also, how do I check for updates when internet is available to the device? I would like both these processes, i.e checking for internet and updating local file to run in the background, while the latest-but-one (the local xml file) is still displayed on screen.

Apologies if this question is vague. I would be glad to add more details if required.

Comment: You are asking too many questions here. Please be precise as to what point of your code you are facing problem. You are almost asking a complete solution.

Comment: Well, my problem is quite simple. Apologies if it was not clear. I know how to store my xml file locally, and use it. The issue is, I want the app to always keep the latest xml file stored. So, I need to check if a new file is available, and if it is, replace the existing xml file by the new one.
PS: I just found out the method to check internet connectivity, so that is no problem. I need only the xml file replacement method. Thankyou.

Comment: If you know how to download the file on internet, save the file locally, I think you know how to replace the file locally by using the same methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the XML file locally, and if internet is available check the date of the local XML file against the server's XML modification date.  If it's newer, pull it down and parse and store the result locally again.